# Get TDataModule in design mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datamodule

How can I get all created objects (of TDataModule type let's say) in design mode (component writing)?

Comment: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28050
Found this article but it must have change in Delphi 2010. Do You have any info/links? I would be greatful.

Comment: please edit the question to clarify (and match the accepted answer). Specifically remove the reference to "autocreated" forms in the title, because it's misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the global Screen object which has hat data.

Comment: Does the "Screen" object hold information at Design Time about the forms that the project is going to auto-create at run time? I'd expect to find a list of forms that the IDE itself has open (it's own windows, forms that are being edited, etc), with no connection to the project that's being edited. The OP says `design mode (component writing)`. If I understood him correctly this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Cosmin That was my understanding of the Q too, but since the OP has accepted, perhaps this answer is what they meant.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't clarify enough. When I put a component onto a form I want it to read all components from available datamods. If datamods are not opened IDE doesn't see them. So I must open wanted datamods before putting the component. I don't see any other way. I can read DPR file, but then I have to open all files in the project and check for TDataModule class which is a bit of hacky.

Comment: @JustMe: then see how various design time editors in the vcl do it. Because really, you do not want all Data modules in your project, but only the ones that are in scope for the form (or datamodule) that is active. For more help on this look for The OTA (Open Tools API), design (time) editors, data-aware controls, etc.